# Add app version check while creating a branch.io deeplink

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

Our mobile apps are hybrid (Native + React Native). Also, we have many active app versions in the market. As per the flow, a nightly job will send WhatsApp notifications to a set of users,with deeplink (created using branch.io). On that deep link click, user should be redirected at the newly built RN screen.

How do we manage redirection in the app with versions < latest version? Ideally, we would want, the user to be redirected to Appstore/Playstore to 'update' app.

Can we set some app version check while creating branch.io deeplinks?

Answer (score 2):

Since Branch links make use of App links on Android and Universal links on iOS. It is the OS that opens the App without any call to Branch servers involved. You can break the universal links by appending ["/e" in your Branch links](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-open-web-instead-of-app).

Note: This would break the universal links for the users having the latest version of your App as well.

An alternative is to re-direct the user to the Play Store/App store from your Application after checking the App version.